# Get map by value from list in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I’m creating a simple service that takes in an email address — and finds the user — from a list of users.

Here’s a simplified version with a list of users. I’d like to extract a user based on their email address.

```
def endpoint do
  [%{email: "foo@example.org", account_type: "full"}, 
   %{email: "bar@earxample.org", account_type: "standard"}, 
   %{email: "baz@example.org", account_type: "full"}]
end

def get_by_email(user, email) do
  user |> Map.get(:email)
end

def dev_endpoint(email) do
  endpoint
  |> Enum.map(&get_by_email(email)/1)
end

def show(conn, %{"id" => email}) do
  response = dev_endpoint(email)
  json(conn, %{"email" => response}) 
end
```

So essentially:

```
dev_endpoint("foo@example.org")
```

Should return:

```
%{email: "foo@example.org", account_type: "full"}
```

I know there’s something wrong with my capture syntax, but I’ve tried various different iterations of it with no luck.

Comment: Maybe I cannot fully understand what you want but Isn't `endpoint |> Enum.find(&(email== Map.get(&1,:email)))` sufficient ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Enum.find/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#find/3). This is how I would use it:

```
def endpoint do
  [%{email: "foo@example.org",   account_type: "full"}, 
   %{email: "bar@earxample.org", account_type: "standard"}, 
   %{email: "baz@example.org",   account_type: "full"}]
end

def find_by_email(email) do
  Enum.find(endpoint, fn u -> u.email == email end)
end
```

Now you can just use this:

```
iex> MyModule.find_by_email("foo@example.org")
%{email: "foo@example.org", account_type: "full"}
```